# turn off the fake bold and italic bits in android

Tags: android, fonts

I have done a function that run through a view and changes the font.
the problem is that in order to avoid the fake bold and italic bits, i set the bolds font this way (and it would be the same for italics) : `e.setTypeface(Constants.fontBold, Typeface.NORMAL);` after testing the `e.getTypeface().getStyle()`

So if I do it this way twice (for an obscur reason), the font would be normal instead of bold. i fell bad letting this kind of possibility in my app. So if somebody has an idea how to disable the fake bold and italic, I would be grateful !

```
public static boolean recursiveFontSetting(View v) {

        if (v instanceof ViewGroup) {
            for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) v).getChildCount(); i++)
                recursiveFontSetting(((ViewGroup) v).getChildAt(i));
            return true;
        } else if (v instanceof TextView) {
            TextView e = (TextView) v;
            if (e.getTypeface() != null
                    && e.getTypeface().getStyle() == Typeface.BOLD) {
                e.setTypeface(Constants.fontBold, Typeface.NORMAL);
            } else {
                e.setTypeface(Constants.font);
            }
            return true;
        } else if (v instanceof Button) {
            Button e = (Button) v;
            if (e.getTypeface() != null
                    && e.getTypeface().getStyle() == Typeface.BOLD)
                e.setTypeface(Constants.fontBold, Typeface.NORMAL);
            else
                e.setTypeface(Constants.font);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Thanks !

Comment: It's not necessary to check TextView and Button separately -- Button is a subclass of TextView.